# ActionChains.perform() works only 1 time

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I automate website https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/ as part of training.

I try to create an action chain which click a button "bigCookie".
I have a loop in range 5000 when I invoke actions.perform().

Unfortunately perform works only the first time. Others iteration have no effect.
Do you know what might cause this? As I know perform should activate all actions.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bigCookie")
cookie_count = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cookies")
product0 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "productPrice0")
product1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "productPrice1")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(cookie).click()

for i in range(5000):
    actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bigCookie")
cookie_count = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cookies")
product0 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "productPrice0")
product1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "productPrice1")

for i in range(5000):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(cookie).click()
    actions.perform()
```

:)